# Is it possible to catch "Send" event on Outlook 2010 add-in in a button's onAction function?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook

Because I'm in the ribbon's class, there is no pointer to the Outlook.Application object. So, I cannot use

```
Application.ItemSend += new ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(MyItemSendEventHandler)
```

this event handler.

How can I reach Outlook.Application object in ribbon class or are there another way to catch send event?

```
public void SendEnMail(Office.IRibbonControl control) //OnAction Function
    {
        Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
        Outlook._MailItem myMail = (Outlook._MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
        myMail.Display(true);
        Outlook.Application application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
        application.ItemSend += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(Application_ItemSend);
    }
    void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        string a = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)Item).Body;
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(a);
        Cancel = true;
    }
```

I cannot catch the ItemSend event like that. but if I write the eventhandler to ThisAddIn class

```
 private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
         Application.ItemSend += new               Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(Application_ItemSend);
    }
void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        string a = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)Item).Body;
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(a);
        Cancel = true;
    }
```

like this, it is working.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this:

```
Outlook.Application application = Outlook.Application.GetActiveInstance();
```

But this should work the same:

```
Outlook.Application application = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Outlook.Application;
```

Or if youre making a COMAddIn you can catch the application object in the OnConnection event.
Hope it helps

Edit:
It makes sence that binding to the event is done when the addin starts. As when you bind to the event on the onAction you will (from that point on) keep catching the ItemSend for every Item the amount of times you clicked the button (as it adds a new handler). You could also try to catch the mail.SendEvent

```
private Outlook.MailItem myMail;
public void SendEnMail(Office.IRibbonControl control) //OnAction Function
{
    myMail = (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
    myMail.Send += mail_Send;
}

void mail_Send(ref bool Cancel)
{
    string a = myMail.Body;
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(a);
    Cancel = true;
}
```

Edit2: 
Excuse me as i'm using a different library. 
According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.itemevents_10_event.send%28v=office.15%29.aspx) it should have been the Send event instead of SendEvent event. I've changed the example accordingly.
Hope it works this time.

I think i see the issue is youre using the _MailItem, which is an interface of the MailItem interface. use the MailItem interface instead

Comment: I'm newbie at C# and Add-In development. So, I cannot understand where to I will write this lines.

Comment: It didn't work again :( 

Error 4 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem' does not contain a definition for 'SendEvent' and no extension method 'SendEvent' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: This time it says, "Cannot assign to 'Send' because it is a 'method group'"

Comment: I've tried to use MailItem interface but it didn't work again. I think I will try another way to do what I want. Thanks for your interest.